# Return value of the 'return_var' if exec function is successful in PHP?

Tags: php

I need some basic information regarding the return values when the `exec()` function is successfully executed. Especially what should be the value of the 'return_var' when `exec` is successful and at the same time what would be in the output array as well and vice-versa.

In my case I am getting a value of `return_var = -6`.

Does it have any proper meaning?

Thanks

Comment: may be reading the manual page for exec can be of some help?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns the return value of the executed program. It thus depends on the executed program on what that return value means.

Answer (score 0):

PHP [`exec()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) documentation is quite straightforward:

> ```
> string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
> ```
>
> *output*:
>
> If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be filled with every line of output from the command. Trailing whitespace, such as \n, is not included in this array. Note that if the array already contains some elements, exec() will append to the end of the array. If you do not want the function to append elements, call unset() on the array before passing it to exec().
>
> *return_var*:
>
> If the return_var argument is present along with the output argument, then the return status of the executed command will be written to this variable.